# Sync a single file from OneDrive/SharePoint to a network drive for all to access

Tags: onedrive, network-drive

I'm looking to have a single folder on a network drive that syncs with a file on OneDrive folder. When trying to move my own computers OneDrive file to the network drive, I get a "file name is not valid or too long" error (I didn't think it would be so easy).

After some Google searching, it maybe that OneDrive doesn't support using an external drive to be used.

I really don't have much experience with SharePoint. It be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Any experts that can help out?